# Assigning a group of models to another model

Tags: python, django, backend

I'm creating a task completion app where a user can create a project, then users can create tickets for that specific project. The problem is that when I create a foreignkey object, it requires a default value. There are no projects right now to set as default.

Here are my models

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=140)



class Post(models.Model):
    LOW = 1
    NORMAL = 2
    HIGH = 3
    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (LOW , 'Low'),
        (NORMAL, 'Normal'),
        (HIGH, 'High'),
    ]

    TYPE_CHOICES = [
        ('Features', 'Feature Request'),
        ('Bug/Error', 'Bug/Error'),
        ('Design', 'Design'),
    ]

    PROGRESS_STATUS = [
        ('Open', 'Open'),
        ('InProgress', 'In Progress'),
        ('AddInfo', 'Additional Info Required'),
        ('Completed', 'Completed'),
    ]



    #all_users = Profile.objects.all()
    #all_user_choices = ((x.user, x.user) for x in all_users)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    priority = models.IntegerField( choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    status = models.CharField(choices=PROGRESS_STATUS, default='Open', max_length=25)
    ticket_type = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default ='Features', max_length=25)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Projects, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    #assigned_developer = models.CharField(choices=all_user_choices, default=author, max_length=50)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) nullable. For example:

```
project = models.ForeignKey(Projects, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None)
```